# Cancel button on Stripe paymentRequestWithCardForm not working in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe integration in my application. I am using the following package:

```
stripe_payment: ^1.0.11
```

Following is my code for Stripe Integration:

```
StripePayment.paymentRequestWithCardForm(CardFormPaymentRequest())
        .then((paymentMethod) {
      _paymentMethod = paymentMethod;
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }).catchError((e) {
      if (e is PlatformException) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        displaysnackbar('Cancelled by user');
      } else {
        print('ERROR $e');
        Navigator.pop(context);
        displaysnackbar('Something went wrong');
      }
    });
```

It is working fine if I enter the card number but when I press the cancel button on the card view which pops up using this function - StripePayment.paymentRequestWithCardForm, it displays the following error:

```
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(cancelled, Cancelled by user, null, null))
```

I have used PlatformException but still it doesn't work.

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try to use the last version `1.1.4` for `stripe_payment`.

And the best solution I think is changing the package to `flutter_stripe` because `stripe_payment` has been **discontinued**.

[image: stripe_payment discontinued]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out it was not any issue, it was showing only in simulator but when I released the app and tested it on TestFlight on iOS, the cancel button worked perfectly.